# javascript: replace ↵ from string

Tags: javascript

I have a super annoying raw data which is littered with `↵` and there's no way I can str.replace('↵','') is there? I tried it and didn't work, I couldn't find anything on this because when I search for `↵` it doesn't show up the ascii code.

Comment: is this a `/n` carriage return character coming back ?

Comment: Try `str.replace('\n',' ')`

Comment: `console.log('a↵b'.replace('↵',''));` works fine for me.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use to replace all '\n'

```
str.replace(/\n/ig, '');
```